# Cannot parse project property android.enableJetifier='true ' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false'

Tags: android

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ghantadilse"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
//noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your post doesn't really have a question in it, but from the error it looks like you have a space after "true".

In `gradle.properties` check that you have `android.enableJetifier=true` without a space behind it.

You need both these lines:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

`android.useAndroidX=true`:

The Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library.

`android.enableJetifier=true`:

The Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries.

Read more here:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: also many error taken when i resolve this i faced    error like annotation ,V4 support

Comment: When i delete it android.enableJetifier=true then faced another problem like 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled

Comment: any suugesstion what will i do

Comment: It also gives error when you put space after android.nonTransitiveRClass=true. My problem was this I wrote like that  "android.nonTransitiveRClass=true " instead "android.nonTransitiveRClass=true"

Answer (score 2):

If you put a space after:

```
"android.useAndroidX = true"
"android.enableJetifier = true"
```

It's creating an error, check that you did not put a last space.

Answer (score 0):

put a space before and after equal. `gradle.properties` file not recognising the syntax.

`android.useAndroidX = true`
`android.enableJetifier = true`

Comment: The only thing this "new" answer does is to repeat what half of the other answers are already saying.